# Error regarding Failed to get Affiliation when registering the user

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have six organizations and two channels. I am trying to set up fabric ca server and register admin and user. 
When I am trying to register a user, I am getting this error"Failed to register user "user-Patient": Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":0,"message":"Registration of 'user-Patient' failed in affiliation validation: Failed getting affiliation 'Patient.department1': : scode: 404, code: 63, msg: Failed to get Affiliation: sql: no rows in result set"}]]" 
I have set the affiliation in fabri-ca-server-config.yaml file.

```
version: 1.4.2
port: 7054

cors:
    enabled: false
    origins:
      - "*"

debug: false
crlsizelimit: 512000


tls:
  enabled: false
  certfile:
  keyfile:
  clientauth:
    type: noclientcert
    certfiles:

ca:
  name:
  keyfile:
  certfile:
  chainfile:

crl:
  expiry: 24h

registry:
  maxenrollments: -1
  identities:
     - name: admin
       pass: adminpw
       type: client
       affiliation: ""
       attrs:
          hf.Registrar.Roles: "*"
          hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles: "*"
          hf.Revoker: true
          hf.IntermediateCA: true
          hf.GenCRL: true
          hf.Registrar.Attributes: "*"
          hf.AffiliationMgr: true

db:
  type: sqlite3
  datasource: fabric-ca-server.db
  tls:
      enabled: false
      certfiles:
      client:
        certfile:
        keyfile:

ldap:
   enabled: false
   url: ldap://<adminDN>:<adminPassword>@<host>:<port>/<base>
   tls:
      certfiles:
      client:
         certfile:
         keyfile:

   attribute:
      names: ['uid','member']
      converters:
         - name:
           value:
      maps:
         groups:
            - name:
              value:

affiliations:
   Patient:
      - department1
     # - department2
   GovtHos:
      - department1
   PHC:
      - department1   
   PvtHos:
      - department1
   Research:
      - department1
   Insurance:
      - department1

signing:
    default:
      usage:
        - digital signature
      expiry: 8760h
    profiles:
      ca:
         usage:
           - cert sign
           - crl sign
         expiry: 43800h
         caconstraint:
           isca: true
           maxpathlen: 0
      tls:
         usage:
            - signing
            - key encipherment
            - server auth
            - client auth
            - key agreement
         expiry: 8760h

csr:
   cn: fabric-ca-server
   keyrequest:
     algo: ecdsa
     size: 256
   names:
      - C: US
        ST: "North Carolina"
        L:
        O: Hyperledger
        OU: Fabric
   hosts:
     - d09fe8ba31b4  ### Dont know
     - localhost
   ca:
      expiry: 131400h
      pathlength: 1

idemix:
  rhpoolsize: 1000
  nonceexpiration: 15s
  noncesweepinterval: 15m

bccsp:
    default: SW
    sw:
        hash: SHA2
        security: 256
        filekeystore:
            keystore: msp/keystore


cacount:
cafiles:

intermediate:
  parentserver:
    url:
    caname:

  enrollment:
    hosts:
    profile:
    label:

  tls:
    certfiles:
    client:
      certfile:
      keyfile:

cfg:
  identities:
    passwordattempts: 10

operations:
    listenAddress: 127.0.0.1:9443

    tls:
        enabled: false
        cert:
            file:
        key:
            file:
        clientAuthRequired: false
        clientRootCAs:
            files: []

metrics:
    provider: disabled
    statsd:
        network: udp
        address: 127.0.0.1:8125
        writeInterval: 10s
        prefix: server
```

Docker-compose-ca.yaml file:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  byfn:

services:
  ca0:  #Patient
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-Patient
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.Patient.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${BYFN_CA1_PRIVATE_KEY}
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.Patient.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${BYFN_CA1_PRIVATE_KEY} -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/Patient.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./fabric-ca-server-config.yaml:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
      #######gfgfgrfg
    container_name: ca_peerPatient
    networks:
      - byfn

  ca1:    #GovtHos
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-GovtHos
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.GovtHos.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${BYFN_CA2_PRIVATE_KEY}
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=8054
    ports:
      - "8054:8054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.GovtHos.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${BYFN_CA2_PRIVATE_KEY} -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/GovtHos.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./fabric-ca-server-config.yaml:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
    container_name: ca_peerGovtHos
    networks:
      - byfn

  ca3:    # PHC
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-PHC
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.PHC.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${BYFN_CA3_PRIVATE_KEY}
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=9054
    ports:
      - "9054:9054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.PHC.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${BYFN_CA3_PRIVATE_KEY} -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/PHC.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./fabric-ca-server-config.yaml:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
    container_name: ca_peerPHC
    networks:
      - byfn

  ca4:  #PvtHos
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-PvtHos
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.PvtHos.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${BYFN_CA4_PRIVATE_KEY}
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=10054
    ports:
      - "10054:10054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.PvtHos.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${BYFN_CA4_PRIVATE_KEY} -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/PvtHos.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./fabric-ca-server-config.yaml:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
    container_name: ca_peerPvtHos
    networks:
      - byfn

  ca5:  #Research
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-Research
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.Research.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${BYFN_CA5_PRIVATE_KEY}
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=11054
    ports:
      - "11054:11054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.Research.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${BYFN_CA5_PRIVATE_KEY} -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/Research.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./fabric-ca-server-config.yaml:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
    container_name: ca_peerResearch
    networks:
      - byfn

  ca6:  #Insurance
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-Insurance
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.Insurance.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${BYFN_CA6_PRIVATE_KEY}
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=12054
    ports:
      - "12054:12054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.Insurance.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${BYFN_CA6_PRIVATE_KEY} -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/Insurance.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./fabric-ca-server-config.yaml:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
    container_name: ca_peerInsurance
    networks:
      - byfn
```

I don't know what is wrong. I am new to hypeldger fabric. Please help me out.
I am using fabric 1.4.2.
Thanks in advance.
[image: Docker container up and running]

Comment: have you tried to list the affiliations to see if they are set up as you expect? Perhaps `bin/fabric-ca-client affiliation list`

Comment: Sir, I am getting command not found sir. What should I do?

Comment: Sir, I just wrote docker-compose-ca.yaml and Fabric-ca-server-config.yaml files. Then I did this ``` docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml -f docker-compose-ca.yaml up -d```.  I want to register Admin and user like they have done in Fabcar example. What should I do sir?

Answer (score 0):

To test your CA you can download the Fabric binaries as described in [this document](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

The you can use [this document](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clientcli.html) to experiment with the fabric-ca client.  (There are sub commands to add and list affiliations.)

You could start by enrolling the admin with something like

`fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054`

(you may find it easier to begin with to disable TLS for testing.)

Then you could try:

`fabric-ca-client affiliation list`